# How can i display TempData in img tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a problem on my Asp .Net Core project. I'm trying to post an image file to local path this works well but i want to use img tag and show this file to user. I'm holding file path in here;

```
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;
    public string _dir;
    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
        _dir = _env.ContentRootPath;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_dir, $"{id}.png"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
            var name = $"{id}.png";
            var filePath = $"{_dir}" + "\\";
            string name2 = name.ToString();
            string filepath = filePath .ToString();
            string file = filepath + name2;
            TempData["link"] = file;
       }
       return new RedirectResult(@"Privacy"); //it can change for example it's Priavcy for now.
   }
```

And this is my .cshtml img tag;

```
    <label>Link:</label><br />
    <img src="@TempData["link"]" alt="Incoming Image" id="link" /><br />
    <textarea cols="102" rows="5" disabled="disabled" style="resize:none;">@TempData["link"]</textarea>
```

and I already use a base64 convert, it didn't work here too;

```
    <img src="@String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(TempData["link"]));" alt="Incoming Image" id="link" />
```

thanks for looking my post, with respect to the community...

Comment: You cannot open a file on server (asp core) in your browser by simply using the path. You can a) provide a GetFile(string name) action or b) write the image DATA to TempData["link"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ContentRootPath` is the local path to the root of your application. A local path only works in the context of the local machine, i.e. in this case the server on which the application is running on. So you can use that path to say where the server should store the path, but to a user, this path doesn’t make any sense because they cannot access your local file system.

Apart from that, the *content* root path is also the path to where your application’s assemblies are, and also where your application’s configuration files are. You generally do not want this folder to be accessible from the outside.

Instead, what you can use is the `WebRootPath` which is the path to the `wwwroot` folder. This folder is served through the static files middleware by default. So the contents here *are* accessible to end users. You just need to construct the correct path:

```
private readonly string _webRootPath;

public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    _webRootPath = env.WebRootPath;
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
{
    var targetFolder = Path.Combine(_webRootPath, "uploads");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var fileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.png";
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(targetFolder, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            file.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }

        // file is stored at `…/wwwroot/uploads/{fileName}`
        // so public path is `/uploads/{fileName}`
        var publicPath = "/uploads/" + fileName;

        TempData["link"] = publicPath;
    }
    return new RedirectResult(@"Privacy");
}
```

The link path is then a link to the file within the `wwwroot` folder, reachable from the outside.

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for answer. When i tried your code the page crashing and show me "InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.TempDataSerializer' cannot serialize an object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile'."

Comment: @BuğrahanBoykız Sorry, made a mistake there, it should be `TempData["link"] = publicPath;`